# How do I define ActiveRecord relationships between two models that relate to each other in two different ways?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, has-many-through

In my app I have the classes  User,  Video, and Vote.  Users and Videos can relate to each other in two different ways: as a one-to-many or as a many-to-many.  The former is when a User submits a Video (one user can submit many videos).  The latter is when a user votes on a video (users have many videos through votes, and vice versa).  Here is my code, which does not work (I think -- I may be doing something wrong in the view).  Please help me understand the correct way to structure these associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, :as => :submissions
  has_many :votes #have tried it without this
  has_many :videos, :as => :likes,  :through => :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :user
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes #have tried it without this . . . superfluous?
  has_many :users, :as => :voters, :through => :votes
end
```

Comment: Could you expand on what doesn't work? Is there an error, etc?

Comment: when I try to do:  video.voters << user, it says "Undefined method 'voters' for #<Video:0xb752b270>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos # Submitted videos
  has_many :votes
  has_many :voted_videos, :through => :votes # User may vote down a vid, so it's not right to call 'likes'
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :user
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
  has_many :voters, :through => :votes
end
```

More details can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gone and checked, but it goes something like this:

Instead of

```
has_many :videos, :as => :likes, :through => :votes
```

Use

```
has_many :likes, :class_name => "Video", :through => :votes
```

Same with the bottom:

```
has_many :users, :as => :voters, :through => :votes
```

becomes

```
has_many :voters, :class_name => "User", :through => :votes
```

`:as` is used for polymorphic associations. See [this chapter in docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833) for more info.

Comment: This set me in the right direction.  The only thing missing is you have to also add :source => :user  & :source => :video.  Then I tried it without the :class_name part and it still worked with just :source.  Thanks!  I'd upvote but I don't have enough rep

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys, definitely pointed me in the right direction.  Here is the working code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, :as => :submissions
  has_many :votes
  has_many :likes, :source => :video, :through => :votes 
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :user
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
  has_many :voters, :source => :user, :through => :votes 
end
```

PS I kept it as :likes because in this app they won't be able to downvote, only upvote.